# Where do we set Parent publishing?

Tags: web8, publishing, web8.5

We have many publication in Tridion 8.5 where certain set of group is parent for specific publication. So if a try to publish any items from parent publication in the Publishing pop-up i can't live Target live where to publish stag or live. So anyone please suggest where configuration needs to changed or looked in to for the same :)

Comment: it is resolved now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the problem is that the **Staging** and **Live** Target Types do not show up in the Publishing Dialogue when you try to publish an item (e.g. a Page or Dynamic Component Presentation).

You would like to use the **Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications** option (within the **Advanced** tab) from the Parent Publication, but are unable to use this because the Target Types are not showing in the **Choose One or More Target Types to Publish to** pane.

[image: Screenshot of the Tridion Publishing Dialogue with no Target Types listed]

Assuming that I've understood the question correctly, then the most likely cause is that publishing is not configured for the Parent Publication or you don't have rights to publish from that Publication.

You'll need to configure publishing within Topology Manager (or the Legacy Publishing GUI) for the Parent Publication (and possibly in the Deployer configuration).

You may also want to look in the **Security** tab of the **Publication Properties** to confirm that your User/Group has the **Publish to Content Distributor** option checked.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :)
Later on I figured out that in Topology manager the mapping of mapping were missing which we added and it resolved.
For that I have right clicked the Parent publication and selected Properties and then after "Publishing" Tab where the mapping of Target type like Live and Stag were missing.

Comment: Excellent. Please feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it helped :)